# Writing PDF blobs to file using coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion-11

I have table with blobs of pdf that I would like to recreate the pdfs in a folder.
I can see how to do this in the browser using `cfcontent`, but this is a maintenance script I would like to run to take blobs out of the database and into a folder structure

This appears to work, but not sure if it is the best way to write the blob to file :

```
<cfquery name="q" datasource= "foo">
  SELECT  ID,blobData,filename
  FROM blobTable 
</cfquery>

<cffile action="write" output="#toBinary(q.blobdata)#" file="d:\pdffoler\#q.FileName#">
```

Comment: Are you asking if there is a more optimal way than your implementation?

Comment: If the database column contains binary, shouldn't need the toBinary().

Comment: yeah is this the most optimal way to create the pdf from a blob and if I don't use the tobinary function I get an invalid file